# Display items over image

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have the following code on [codepen page](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/vQwZRw). (included for code-running purposes - doesn't work in the snippet) The goal is be able display the `<div class="item__boxes">` element at the bottom of the `<div class="item">`.

**Question**

How would I display the `<div class="item__boxes">` element at the bottom of the `<div class="item">`?

**Goal:**

1. As the height of the `<div class="item__text">` increases due to content inside of it, there should always be some padding/margin between the text and the `<div class="item__boxes">`.
2. `<div class="item__boxes">` should always display at the bottom of the `<div class="item">` element regardless of breakpoint.

**Current Issue**

[image: current issue with banner]

**Desired output**

[image: desired output with banner]

**Code**

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
}
.item__wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.item__img img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.item__text {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
  padding: 64px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item__boxes {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.col-padding {
  padding: 16px;
}
.col-m-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-t-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item__wrapper">
<div class="item">
 <div class="item__img">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature">
    <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/960/480/nature">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
  </picture>
 </div>
 <div class="item__text">
  <h3>Some title</h3>
  <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item__boxes">
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
   <div>Some Title</div>
   <div>Enthusiastically incubate diverse initiatives without multifunctional strategic theme areas.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
   <div>Globally Title</div>
   <div>Globally impact integrated infomediaries via seamless mindshare. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
   <div>Distinctively Title</div>
   <div>Distinctively strategize long-term high-impact ideas whereas client-centered leadership skills.</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code here, on stackoverflow, as links break, and question will become unhelpful to future users. It also makes it easier for us to see the issue!

Comment: @RachelGallen When I initially include the code i was getting warning that there was too much code compared to text so i moved it over to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/vQwZRw). It is added now.

Comment: @RachelGallen the snippet feature does not display my output correctly as well so i used codepen in hopes of making it easier.

Comment: yes I see that, but it's good to include both if that's the case.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQGPep opaque picture background with text,  adjujstable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played about with your code. 
In order for there to be always some padding no matter how wide, you'll have to use relative positioning on the text and absolutely position the image. As-is the padding-bottom will vary depending on how wide it is, I recommend you **include the image as a `background-image` and set the size of the background-image to `cover` in the css**, this way there will be no gap, no matter how wide/narrow/tall/short your screen is. I tried out the given code at 80% width, and set the padding to 33% (I didn't put the background image code in) At 50%, your initial width, there was no bottom padding required.

The snippet code won't run because of the css structure but I'm including it anyway for future reference. Here is a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVOzoP), and a [second one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQGPep)

Hope this helps

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  &__wrapper {
    max-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  &__img {
    img {
      top: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%!important;
    }
  }
  &__text {
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    //padding-bottom:33vh at 80%;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: top;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  &__boxes {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}

.col {
  &-padding {
    padding: 16px 16px 5px 16px;
  }
  &-m-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col {
    &-t-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item__wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__img">
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature">
        <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/960/480/nature">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="item__text">
      <h3>Some title</h3>
      <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally
        procrastinate. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__boxes">
    <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
      <div>Some Title</div>
      <div>Enthusiastically incubate diverse initiatives without multifunctional strategic theme areas.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
      <div>Globally Title</div>
      <div>Globally impact integrated infomediaries via seamless mindshare. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">
      <div>Distinctively Title</div>
      <div>Distinctively strategize long-term high-impact ideas whereas client-centered leadership skills.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by using `background-image` i would have to remove the `<picture>` element, which was used for performance reasons to serve different images based on breakpoint. Also, the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVOzoP) that you provided does not solve the problem. It appears to add more space between the two elements when view on a screen that is >1536px wide. Any thoughts?

Comment: @usernameabc the issue you highlight would be solved by using background-image:cover;

Comment: @usernameabc if it's the opacity you are worried about, look at this fiddle (It's adapted from an earlier fiddle of mine, I removed previous jquery and hover that I had in it) https://jsfiddle.net/w8qnLhrs/ (this was the original : https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qj9tvrtf/) I definitely think it's a feasible option.

Comment: using your [second one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQGPep) codepen, I was able to get it working in this [Items over carousel using background-image](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/eQwgdB). I am now going to continue testing on our live site and report back the update.

Comment: Based on the description and what you have, this is the solution that worked.

Comment: @usernameabc happy to help